# What is the number one or the most recommended Talmud/Gemara passage for a child to begin studying?

Tags: talmud-gemara, torah-study, children-parenting, chinuch-education

What is the number one or the most recommended Talmud/Gemara passage for a child to begin studying?

I understand that the number one or the most recommended Torah passage for a child to begin studying is:
“The Torah that Moshe commanded us is the heritage of the congregation of Yaakov.” [Deut. 33:4]

Comment: @ninamag I would assume the "eylu devarims" that are said in morning brachos would be learned quite early. Are you talking about serious learning or kriah?

Comment: @SAH That would be good to clarify

Comment: recommendations for both serious learning or kriah are welcome.

Comment: Almost duplicate: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/299/talmud-study-where-to-start

Comment: @ninamag OK then for kriah, undoubtedly this, by age 5 or so. http://www.chabadhebrewschool.us/Templates/Hebrewschool/article_cdo/aid/817553

Comment: @ninamag ...Or else Ma Nishtana, or else בְּכָל דוֹד וָדוֹר חַיָיב אָדָם לִרְאוֹת אֶת עַצְמוֹ כְּאִלוּ הוּא יָצָא מִמִצְרָיִם כָּל יִשְׂרָאֵל יֵשׁ לָהֶם חֵלֶק לְעוֹלָם הַבָּא   or   שֶׁנֶאֱמַר וְעַמֵךְ כּוּלָם צַדִיקִים לְעוֹלָם יִירְשׁוּ אָרֶץ נֵצֶר מַטָעַי מַעֲשֵׂה יָדַי לְהִתְפָּאֵר

Comment: Near Duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53778/why-do-many-boys-begin-learning-gemara-with-elu-metzios

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I would close this for being opinion based, but, since I can't...

You can find different people's opinions all over the Internet ([various forums that come up when you Google this question in Hebrew](https://www.google.ca/search?client=opera&q=%D7%91%D7%90%D7%99%D7%96%D7%94%20%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%9B%D7%AA%20%D7%92%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%90%20%D7%99%D7%A9%20%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9C&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)), however, I will try to extract the useful information (and Rabbinic opinions) from the various results...

From [one Otzar Hachochma forum](http://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=28746), a useful piece of information is Sye510's point above in the comments to Ezra's answer (which also seems to be a popular starter from my non-Chabad experience):

> שמעתי פעם שהעניין שאמרו ללמוד בבא מציעא ואלו מציאות תחילה זה לחנכו בזהירות ממון מתחילתו.

More important is the quote there from Sefer Chovas Hatalmidim that children should (and/or do) begin with Perek Shenayim Ochzin, there is a copy of the page in that thread.

Also there, a suggestion from Kuntres Devar Malchus to begin with Maseches Megillah.

[Another linked Otzar Hachochma discussion](http://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=24872) brings various sources in Rishonim about Perek Ein Omdin being the easiest/simplest, and features other interesting sources as well

[Here](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/?cat=515), Harav Yitzchak Ben Yosef (I don't think there is any relation to Harav Yitzchak Yosef) suggests Megillah and Berachos:

> ללמוד גמרא עם רש"י זה מצוין עדיף להתמקד במסכת אחת ולהמשיך עם אחרת.
>   מסכתות בסדר מועד ,טוב להתחיל בלימוד , מסכת מגילה ברכות.
>   אבל ללמוד מסכת אחת.

The "Tzevet" of Yeshivas Tzefas [here](http://www.kipa.co.il/%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%9C-%D7%90%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91/%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9A-%D7%9C%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93-%D7%92%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%90/) suggests Megillah/Taanis/Chagigah for a child beginning on his own.

Rav Yosef Alnakwa (?) [here](http://shut.moreshet.co.il/shut2.asp?id=39031) suggests the first Perek of Berachos for an older beginner.

(I would also check out [this link](http://shlomo-aviner.net/index.php/%D7%90%D7%99%D7%96%D7%94_%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%9B%D7%AA_%D7%9C%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93_%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94%3F), but the video doesn't load for me.)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what other people's experiences were, but the first Gemara I ever learned was [Bava Metzia 21](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Metzia.21a.7-19?lang=bi), "Perek Eilu Metzios". The sugya concerns lost and abandoned property in the reshus harabim. My experience is coming from a Chabad yeshiva katanah.

(Personally, I have heard of people beginning with [Berachos 26](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.26a.11?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), "Perek Tefilas HaShachar". This was the second Gemara I ever learned. See mbloch's comment in [rabbi's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/90410/11486) below.)

Concerning kriyah:

In Chabad, children memorize the [Twelve Pessukim](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2313797/jewish/The-12-Torah-Passages.htm), a collection of twelve passukim from the Tanach or elsewhere, as encouraged by the last Lubavitcher Rebbe.

Sorry all my experience is coming from Chabad; they were in charge of my Jewish education. :)

Comment: Yes, Eilu Metzios is pretty universal as a child's starter.

Comment: To add to @ezra's answer:  I believe the reason why Bava Metzi'a is the first masechta/tractate that young boys in yeshiva is because it is important to teach the children when there still young what belongs to them/ what they can take and what must be given back which will hopefully make an impression for the rest of their lives.

Comment: @Sye510 There are quite many more practical sugyot out there (see Berakhot). I suppose that part contains many important theoretical concepts that are relevant for later studies, and that is why most people choose that one (instead of Berakhot).

Comment: @ezra I might not have been clear. Instead of Berakhot (which is the beginning of Mishna and Gemara), roughly 90% percent of the people I know started with Bava Metzia, and particularly Eilu Metziot, since it contains these important concepts which are not really present in Berakhot. (If that matters, I started with Berakhot, and it's obviously practical for everyday life, and less difficult to understand.)

Comment: @Sye510 see the answer which I will IYH post in a little while

Comment: This answer is pure opinion with no sources (albeit likely true).  Why is there such a voting discrepancy between this answer and Rabbi's answer below?  (Other than perhaps timing...)

Comment: @רבותמחשבות I believe the reason is because rabbi made a sweeping generalization (that "the whole of klal yisroel starts with eilu metzios") whereas my answer makes it clear that **this was only my experience**, and I can't speak for others. Also, concerning the Twelve Pessukim, I did source that.

Comment: @ezra you're (as usual) probably correct about that.  As I note below, I don't think this is a good MY question, and I do believe that it is common practice to start with that.  Shkoyach!

Answer (score 2):

In *L'maan Yeid'u... Bonim Yivaleidu* Mordechai Shusterman writes  (p. 289) that the [melamed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melamed) of the [Tzemach Tzedek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menachem_Mendel_Schneersohn)'s children asked the Tzemech Tzedek what masechta he should start learning with the children. The Tzemach Tzedek replied that the [Ba'al Shem Tov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baal_Shem_Tov) had begun learning Shas to bring up the Torah that Jews had learned but had not been brought up. However, he only got up to page 17 in Eruvin when he died, so the Tzemach Tzedek told the melamed to start from Eruvin page 17.

> ר' הלל סיפר שהוא היה פעם המלמד של בני הצמח צדק בשנות ילדותם ופעם שאל
>   את הצמח צדק איזו מסכת יתחיל ללמוד עמם ויען אדמו"ר הצמח צדק הבעש"ט
>   התחיל ללמוד ש"ס כדי להעלות את כל התורה של כל ישראל שלמדו ולא עלתה
>   למעלה (כידוע מפרק ל"ו בתניא) והתחיל ללמוד מסכת ברכות שבת ועירובין עד
>   דף י"ז ואחר כך נסתלק על כן תתחיל מדף י"ז

Answer (score -2):

If the whole of klal yisroel starts with eilu metzios [which they do] that's the biggest and best source of its credibility

Comment: This answer would be significantly improved if you can provide a source for your assertion the "the whole of klal yisroel starts with eil [sic] metzios".

Comment: FTR, my (fairly traditional) elementary school did not start teaching gemara with Eilu Metziot.

Comment: Neither did mine...

Comment: find a single orthodox charedi school [folowing a tradition that was trasmitted from the rabbis] that doesn't. [I don't know what faily traditional means doesnt sound too orthodox to me]. a school that is not following mesorah will have results very different from the ones intended. btw: the passage mentioned in the question is what is taught when he first starts speaking an not what he is first taught when he reaches the gemarah level

Comment: see here words from rebbi moshe feinstein http://www.otzar.org/wotzar/book.aspx?160532&pageid=P0005.LST&rect=-50,1144,1699,2152&pagewidth=1716

Comment: My sons' dati leumi school in Israel started with the 4th perek of Brakhot. Does this mean we are not part of klal Yisrael?

Comment: @mbloch Perek Tefillas HaShachar was the second Gemara I ever learned.

Comment: @rabbi Notice how you've now moved from "the whole of klal yisroel" to "orthodox charedi school [following a tradition that was transmitted from the rabbis]".|| In terms of my elementary school, it was founded by impeccably Orthodox German Jews, had (and probably still has) a _limmudei kodesh_ staff that was primarily Chareidi, but served a parent body that I would describe as more Centrist Orthodox.

Comment: @mbloch it means that the dati leumi school is creating its own new mesorah [thats an oximoron statment] rather than staying with the true mesorah. btw: the concept of dati leumi is a new concept. the only form of judaism that has stayed in its original form is that of the ultraorthodox ana chareidim]. how many baalei teshuvah [of the aproximately 1000000 that exist today] became dati leumi? did you check the link from reb moshe feinstein?!

Comment: @rabbi my comment was really reacting to your statement that « all klal Israel did X » which is either wrong or suggests you define klal Israel as only those who teach elu metziot first. PS do you really think that David Hamelech didn’t send his kids to the army or wore a black coat? Tanach clearly shows otherwise

Comment: Dovid Hamelech certainly didn't change the mesorah in klal yisroel nor start a new one. [he did teach us that its never too late to get back on track!]